# Kafka Storm Spout: Got fetch request with offset out of range

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

We have a scenario in our Storm topology where the KafkaSpouts are unable to consume any messages from the topics.  The Spout continuously logs the same WARN message:

> Got fetch request with offset out of range

```
...
2016-10-26 11:11:31.070 o.a.s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Partition{host=somehost.org:9092, topic=my-topic, partition=0} Got fetch request with offset out of range: [3]
2016-10-26 11:11:31.078 o.a.s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Partition{host=somehost.org:9092, topic=my-topic, partition=0} Got fetch request with offset out of range: [3]
2016-10-26 11:11:31.084 o.a.s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Partition{host=somehost.org:9092, topic=my-topic, partition=0} Got fetch request with offset out of range: [3]
2016-10-26 11:11:31.098 o.a.s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Partition{host=somehost.org:9092, topic=my-topic, partition=0} Got fetch request with offset out of range: [3]
2016-10-26 11:11:31.104 o.a.s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Partition{host=somehost.org:9092, topic=my-topic, partition=0} Got fetch request with offset out of range: [3]
2016-10-26 11:11:31.111 o.a.s.k.KafkaUtils [WARN] Partition{host=somehost.org:9092, topic=my-topic, partition=0} Got fetch request with offset out of range: [3]
...
```

The Spout is configured to read the last commit offset from zookeeper and that offset in this scenario is greater then the newest message offset in Kafka.  We are also looking into why the topics offsets are resetting.

Currently we resolve the issue by observing the out of range warning in the storm logs, delete the zookeeper offset entry and then re-deploy the topology.

Comment: Did you recently point your spout to a new topic name? Do you have multiple spouts with the same ID?

Comment: The issue mainly occurs in dev environments so I could see a 'misleading' offset committed to zookeeper.  I am hoping to configure the KafkSpout to give-up the endless loop of getting the out of range offset and either go back to the earliest or latest offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, this was happening because I had recreated the Kafka topic which my KafkaSpout was subscribing to.

The offset for a particular partition is saved in Zookeeper and if a topic is deleted and then created again, you will have to delete the offset info manually from Zookeeper.

Just open the Zookeeper CLI and then delete the path on which the 'node'  belonging to the consumer 'group-id' of your KafkaSpout exists.
For help refer, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/zookeeper/zookeeper_cli.htm

Comment: This was our work around when the scenario was observed.  Delete the zookeeper kafka entry and re-deploy the topology.

Answer (score 0):

If an invalid offset is committed, client configuration "auto.offset.reset" is used. It accepts values "smallest" and "largest". If the value is not set, an exception is thrown (as in your case).

For `KafkaSpout` you can set this value via variable `KafkaConfig#startOffsetTime`  setting it either to `kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime()` or `kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime()`.

See http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/storm-kafka.html

Comment: Our Kafka configuration is for a Storm KafkaSpout and I do not see a property similar to "auto.offset.reset" in the Kafka/SpoutConfig.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The Latest/EarliestTime() have no change on the behaviour.  Stepping through PartitionManager and KafkaUtils I can see the Latest or Earliest offsets returned but PartitionManger ignores them in favour of the zookeeper committed values.

Comment: Standard behavior of Kafka consumer client is to use Latest/Earliest in case committed offset is invalid. If offset is valid, it should be used of course and Latest/Earliest setting has no effect. So a client always resumes from where it left of (as long as committed offset is still valid). If you have a committed offset and want to reset to a specific point in time, you need to do this manually and KafkaSpout does not support this at all -- you need to do it externally. Maybe this questions helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271847/how-to-reset-kafka-offsets-to-match-tail-position

Comment: Maybe Storm's KafkaSpout implementation as a Kafka consumer client is just crappy.